# How did Euler and Bernoulli prove this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, math-history

How did the Euler and Bernoulli know that $\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+\frac1x)^x$ exists?

Comment: What is the definition of $e$?

Comment: I know my limit is the definition of $e$, I'm just asking how did the people who discover this limit (both Euler of Bernoulli had something to do with it)  prove that the limit is equal to a constant.

Comment: You start your question saying "Prove that the [limit] ... is actually equal to $e$."   *Sometimes* that limit (whose existence needs to justified of course) is used as the definition of $e$, sometimes not.  If you are assuming that, could you please adjust the first sentence accordingly?  If you want to show that this limit corresponds to $e$ by some other definition, could you please add that information?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I hope it's better now.

Comment: Wenn you just write out function names like that, $\TeX$ interprets that as a juxtaposition of variable names and formats it accordingly. To get the appropriate font and spacing, you can use predefined commands like `\ln`, or, if you need an operator name for which there isn't a predefined command, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: The question hasn't become any clearer through the edit. It's still not clear on the basis of which definition you want to see a proof that the limit is $\mathrm e$. Also, it makes no sense to ask whether the limit is equal to a constant. The only question that can be asked without providing some other definition of $\mathrm e$ is whether the limit exists; if it exists, it is necessarily a constant, since the only variable in it is the dummy variable $x$.

Comment: There is a pretty nice proof for why the above expression is equal to $\sum \frac{1}{n!}$, but that is really just a conversion between two definitions of $e$.

Comment: OK so the question is: how do you prove that this limit exists without assuming any prior knowledge of e.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $A$ be a constant such that the derivative of $f(t) = A^t$ at $t = 0$ is less than one.  Then for $t$ sufficiently small we have $1 + t > A^t$.  Likewise if the derivative of $B^t$ is greater than one at $t=0$ then for $t$ small we have $1+t < B^t$.  Setting $t = \frac{1}{x}$ shows that $A < (1+\frac{1}{x})^x < B$ for $x$ sufficiently large.  So the limit is equal to the unique constant $e$ such that the derivative of $e^t$ at $t = 0$ is actually equal to one (my favorite definition of $e$).

I don't know how Euler proved it but if you want to find out you should read his book "Introduction to Analysis of the Infinite".

Answer (score 3):

Your edited question is simply, how do we know that 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} (1+1/x)^x$$ exits?  In modern terminology, we might define $f(x)=(1+1/x)^x$, show that $f$ is increasing and bounded above, and deduce that the limit is the [supremum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supremum) of the set of function values for positive $x$, i.e.
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = \sup \{f(x):x>0\}.$$

But, honestly, I think that Euler and his contemporaries largely took this kind of thing for granted, feeling that no proof was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Expand both sides in a Taylor series to prove that they are equal.

This is the same idea as used to show $e^{ix} = \cos(x)+i\sin(x)$. If sine is expanded as a Taylor series, multiply it by $i$, and then added to the Taylor series for cosine, it equal the Taylor series for $e^{ix}$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how Euler proved it, but here's an elementary proof (I'm expanding on Mark McClure's answer).

**Claim 1.** The sequence $x_n:=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is strictly increasing.

**Proof.** The binomial expansion of $x_{n+1}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$ has $n+1$ terms, the last being $\frac{1}{(n+1)^{n+1}}>0$. We prove that the first $n$ terms are greater than or equal to the corresponding $n$ terms in the expansion of $x_n$, so that $x_{n+1}> x_n$ for all $n\geq 1$ (the strict inequality is due to the last term of $x_{n+1}$).

We need to prove that $\binom{n+1}{k}\frac{1}{(n+1)^k}\geq \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}$ for all $k=0,...,n$.

This is clearly true when $k=0$ and we proceed by induction on $k$. Indeed:
\begin{align*}
\binom{n+1}{k+1}\frac{1}{(n+1)^{k+1}}&=\binom{n+1}{k}\frac{1}{(n+1)^k}\cdot \frac{(n-k+1)}{(n+1)(k+1)}\\
&\geq \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}\cdot \frac{(n-k+1)}{(n+1)(k+1)}\\
&=\binom{n}{k+1}\frac{1}{n^{k+1}}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{n(n-k+1)}{(n+1)(n-k)}}_{=\frac{n^2-(k-1)n}{n^2-(k-1)n-k}\geq 1}\\
&\geq \binom{n}{k+1}\frac{1}{n^{k+1}} _\blacksquare 
\end{align*}

**Claim 2.** The sequence $x_n$ is bounded above.

We define $e_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}$ and prove that $x_n\leq e_n$ for all $n\geq 1$. Clearly $e_n$ is increasing and we can easily verify that it is bounded above (by comparing it with the convergent series $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2^k}$ for $k\geq 4$, for example). This is enough to show that $x_n$ is bounded above.

Again we look at the binomial expansion of $x_n$ and compare it term-by-term with $e_n$ and conclude that $x_n\leq e_n$ for all $n\geq 1$.

It suffices to prove that $\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}\leq \frac{1}{k!}$ for all $k=0,...,n$. This is obvious for $k=0$. By induction on $k$,
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k+1}\frac{1}{n^{k+1}}&=\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}\cdot \frac{(n-k)}{n(k+1)}\\
&\leq \frac{1}{k!}\cdot \frac{(n-k)}{n(k+1)}\\
&=\frac{1}{(k+1)!}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{n-k}{n}}_{\leq 1}\\
&\leq \frac{1}{(k+1)!}_\blacksquare  
\end{align*}

**Remark.** This is not enough to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}e_n$, and I haven't come up with a proof of it yet. But I can imagine an explicit one by looking at each $\binom{n}{k}$ as a polynomial on $n$ of degree $k$ and noticing that $x_n=e_n+\frac{p(n)}{n^n}$ where $p$ is some polynomial of degree $\leq n-1$. This suggests (but does not prove) that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p(n)}{n^n}=0$, which looks pretty convincing.

Answer (score 0):

It would be tedious before computers, but you can find that limit simply by plugging in some large numbers. If *n* = 100 you get 2.704. If *n* = 1000 you get 2.716. If *n* = 10000 you get 2.718. Plug in 69! (Wolfram Alpha won't go much higher) and you have 20 or so decimal places that won't change. The digits that already exist won't change no matter how high *n* gets. It follows that if *n* is infinite, then the resulting number has reached a point where the decimal places aren't changing at all.

The result takes the form of $\frac{(x+1)^x}{x^x}$, which may be somewhat easier to expand. I can offer something of a heuristic proof for a limit with an example in [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281+%2B+1%2Fx%29ˆ200) — notice how as the numerator gets larger, the exponent of the denominator gets significantly larger with it.

Comment: Is there a way however to prove that the limit exists? I know that with some limits if you plug in  numbers it looks like it's going to give you a value but past a point it can quickly jump to another value.

Comment: This does not answer the question.